# Toggle Custom UITableViewCell Radio Button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom cell where it displays a table like structure with multiple columns.

**Each row has a column that is a button** that will perform different tasks.

My issue is trying to get the middle column to communicate its state with the other rows.

Initially everything will be grey (not selected) but, when I tap the middle column button, the state will be green. When I select a different row that button will turn green and the previous row would be grey.

Again, each column in the row is a button that does something different (i.e. the right button loads up a modal view). I have tried to use 
`didSelectRowAtIndexPath` but, with the overlapping custom views it does not seem to read the selection.

Any help would be appreciated

[image]

Comment: I worked worked on a simialr issue but the solution is in SWIFT?

Comment: @Md.IbrahimHassan Can you share it please? Swift syntax is fine for me